# Invalid name error when joining servers

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Every time I try to connect it says `invalid name`. Could you give me some tips to help fix that? I have tried restarting my game but that didn't work. I also tried a different server but that also did not work. Does anyone know what my problem is?

Comment: you will need to provide more information than you have. First, what version is your client, second what version is the server (are they the same or compatible). Is the server vanilla, bukkit/spigot or other modded or forge modded? Has the client be modified in any way? (either forgeloader or hacked). have you checked http://xpaw.ru/mcstatus/ to see if the minecraft login servers etc are online at the time? What is the full message you get on the screen and do you have a log? Have you tried deleting your client and installing a fresh vanilla copy (downloaded from minecraft legit server)?

Comment: I'm 95% certain this is about Pocket Edition, since this is a common error there, and I've not heard of this problem with PC Minecraft ever before. So I'll treat it like that until OP says otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to update your minecraft version with of the server.
E.g. I created a server on minecraft 0.13.1 and you try to connect the server with minecraft 0.13.0 so, it will say invalid name error